# AngularFire Map Explanation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

If someone could explain to me how this code really works it would be great, I read the docs but didn't really understand it. It's probably because I instantly jumped to Angular Fire without learning the previours Firebase techniques.

```
    constructor(afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
  afDb.list('items').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
  }).subscribe(items => {
    return items.map(item => item.key);
  });
}
```

What I really don't understand is the ...action.payload.val() and how it works, but also why there are two maps? With the second map I can't reach the properties of the object I want.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

Video I learned map and basing it from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtHHvQ6zlTw

Any source or video where I could learn more about it would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your example, but refactored it a bit, to make it more understandable. It now consists in two parts

1) creating the link to the server (no fetching) and do any change to the response

2) fetching the response (subscribe)

Map has the ability to change the response "on the fly" of the observable, so it controls what the subscribers will get. The first map is to read the response as an array. The second map is to read each item in the array, and for each item we want it to consist of its data and we also want it to have the ID. So now when we subscribe to this function, we will get an array of objects with data + id.

```
//Function that returns an subscribe-able observable
fetchItems() {
    return afDb.list('items')
       .snapshotChanges()
       .map((arr) => {
          return arr.map((snap) => {
            const obj = snap.payload.doc.data();
            obj.id = snap.payload.doc.id;
            return obj;
          });
        });
      }
   }
```

And subscribing to it (remember nothing happens until something subscribes to an observable)

```
//Calls the function and subscribe to the response 
fetchItems()
    .subscribe((res) => {
         console.log('res: ', res);
     });
```